# Не работает горизонтальный скролл

Tags: html, css3, прокрутка

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrapper .item{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 10px solid white;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 110px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Не работает что посоветуйте ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посоветую в блоки item вставить контент что-бы они не сжимались. Или как я вставил паддинги которые не дают сжиматься бокам.

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrapper .item{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 10px solid white;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 110px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    padding: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спосибо большое выручили :)))))